# Graph api - public status from non-friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Graph API, is it possible to retrieve status from a non-friend assuming that they are public?

I have tried retrieving public statuses using the Facebook C# SDK by issuing a GET request with parameters '/user id/statuses', but I am getting an empty result even though I know that some statuses are publicly available.

**UPDATE:** Today it seems that I am able to see public statuses from non-friends by reading `/posts` (sometimes even `/statuses`) on the user. Anyone aware of a resolved bug from Facebook?

**UPDATE:** And today not working again. It works with the Graph API Explorer, but not with a token requested from my test application

Comment: It could be whatever; it could be your person on Facebook.

Comment: I know just wanted an example because I did not find one myself ( a non-friend with public statuses)

Comment: Ok, I see. Some people post publicly, and I want to fetch their statuses through the Graph API

Answer (score 0):

You can get the posts through **Feed** like this:

```
$facebook->api("/USER_ID/feed");
```

This will fetch all the public posts of the user, if he is not your friend.

Comment: I guess the functionality was bugged last week then. On Thursday, it did not work.

On another note, isnt it '/posts' that I want to look at? Isnt '/feed' also including posts from others?