# Public feed from non-friend - changes/bugs?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I used to be able to retrieve the public feed for non-friends. It seems that I always get an empty list now.

Procedure:

- I uses https://graph.facebook.com//feed with my access token
- No matter which version of the API I use, I get the same empty list of posts

Anyone aware of any changes to privacy settings etc. that could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You should never have been able to get access to the public feed of non-friends. Even access to the own feed is restricted nowaday, because `read_stream` will most likely not get approved by Facebook.

Just because something is "public" does not mean you can grab it with the Facebook API.

Comment: I had a question some time ago about roughly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123850/graph-api-public-status-from-non-friend Was it a mistake that it worked back then?

Comment: if you are able to get access to the public feed of a non friend, you should file a bug. because it should definitely not be possible.